# Basic networking questions

Tags: networking

I am trying to understand how exactly **routing** works:

1. if 2 computers are on the same network
2. if they are on different networks.

More specifically I am trying to understand this: [Routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWwnt.png)

I am also trying to understand the difference between

1. IP Address,
2. Net Address,
3. Mac Address.

From what I understand:

1) IP Address: is used when computers communicate on the internet only.

2) Net Address: is a local version of the IP address and each device on the network has a unique net address. It's used when devices on the same network want to communicate with each other.

3) Mac Address: is a globally unique address and no other computer in the world has the same Mac address. In reality this is not true because it can be changed. **It's used when ???**

**When a computer wants to communicate with another on the same network, they use net address, right? If the computers are on different networks what exactly happens?**

**Question:** Can someone please fix my mistakes if any and explain what I am missing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are many network types, but since the most used ones are Ethernet and IP networks (and you seem to be asking about them), I will answer shortly based on them.

IP addresses are always used. They may not be used for deciding who gets the packets directly, but they are the basis even in local networks, since it is an IP network. There can also be other network types that have their own mechanisms, but they are not that common.

In local Ethernet the machines ask via ARP protocol "who has this IP address?" and get a reply with a MAC address. After that they send and receive packets based on that MAC address. The packets still have the IP address information, otherwise the receiving machine wouldn't know what is the destination. Do note that the receiving machine might be a firewall or other middleware device, not the actual computer that has the address. Also a single machine and network card may have several IP addresses set up for it.

In IP networks the IP address is used for routing. All routing devices have a routing table that will tell where the packets should go. If it's a simple device, it usually has a local network and everything else goes via a *default gw*, which will know better what to do with the packets.

A home router will just push them to the operator, there another router will know what addresses go to their networks, others are pushed forward via another connection, until a bigger place is reached where there are inter-operator connections and they choose again the correct route. And then it goes to smaller and smaller pipes the other way around.

Comment: Does "net address" in the picture above mean a private IP address?

Comment: @NET_GUY It can be a private or a public IP address, some machines only have one

Comment: One last question: does the image above describe routing or forwarding?